# Как скомпилировать java-файл из консоли?

Tags: java, компиляция

как скомпилировать java-файл из консоли?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Для компиляции Java-файлов используется компилятор javac из комплекта JDK.

Пример:

```
javac Main.java
```